# Hibernate enum throw Unknown name value [true] for enum class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, enums, hibernate-mapping

I am using MySQL and I have a columns data type as **Enum**, I have define an enum type in my Entity However when query executes to retrive data it throws following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown name value [true] for enum class [com.myproject.MyEnum]
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType$NamedEnumValueMapper.fromName(EnumType.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType$NamedEnumValueMapper.getValue(EnumType.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.nullSafeGet(EnumType.java:107)
```

Following is my Entity and Enum source

```
public enum MyEnum {
    TRUE("true"),
    FALSE("false");

    private final String name;

    private MyEnum (String name){
        this.name = name;
    } 

    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

In my table structure I have define enum{true,false}

```
@Entity
@Table(name="networthcashother")
public class Networthcashother {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String assetName;
    private String assetDescription;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private MyEnum  married; 

    public MuEnum getMarried() {
        return married;
    }

    public void setMarried(MyEnum married) {
        this.married = married;
    }
}
```

However If I change my entity property type from Enum to boolean it works fine. Whats m doing wrong.

Answer (score 7):

The `EnumType.STRING` will use the `Enum` String representation, meaning it will call:

- toString() - when converting the `Enum` to a `String` representation
- [valueOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29) - when converting the `String` representation back to an `Enum`

Because you can't override `valueOf()`, the default implementation will use the value returned by `name()` instead.

To fix it, you need to add the following static method to your Enum:

```
public static MyEnum getEnum(String value) {
    for(MyEnum v : values())
        if(v.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) return v;
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Comment: when will this method get called ? would it be an implicit call made while converting String to Enum or do i have to make this call?

Comment: @VladMihalcea when will this method get called ? or I need to manually call that mathod

Comment: This method will be called automatically by Hibernate. Basically, you just override the default implementation of this method.